# Querying Office for National Statistics data using SPARQL

Tags: graph, azure-data-factory, sparql, rdf, power-automate

I'm trying to get some information from the https://statistics.data.gov.uk/data/postcodes and load the data into SQL Server.

Linked Data is stored in graphs. We keep dataset contents (the data) separately from the metadata, to make it easier for you to find exactly what you need.

The data in this dataset are stored in the graph:
http://statistics.data.gov.uk/graph/postcodes

The metadata about this dataset are stored in the graph:
http://statistics.data.gov.uk/graph/postcodes/metadata

I have no idea how to use the SPARQL engine on the site to get the information or even the metadata.

I have tried the instructions mentioned in the website https://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparql  (API tab) in Azure data factory but no output. I'm not sure how to write the SPAQL queries to retrieve the ONS postcodes data

Comment: Given that I don't know what exactly you need from the data, all I can provide you is this query: `SELECT *
WHERE {
 GRAPH <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/graph/postcodes> { ?s ?p ?o}
} LIMIT 100` which gives you 100 "triples" from the postcodes graph. But I don't know what you mean by "no output" given that I don't know what you tried with SPARQL. Or is it more about Azure data factory?

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate connector for SPARQL engine in ADF.

When I tried below sample URL provided in API section of [this](https://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparq) document .

```
 http://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparql.json?query=SELECT+%2A+WHERE+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%7D+LIMIT+10
```

In rest API connector I used the above URL it gave me the result as below

[image]

When I tried the similar thing for Postcodes URL it is not returning anything

```
http://statistics.data.gov.uk/graph/postcodes
```

Also, in browser when I Open this URL its showing `Error:Not found` plese varify the data is present there.